# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`  error and its count is increasing tremendously even above 3000 times. as shown in the following images.

[image: Jquery error]

[image: jquery error undefined]

I also tri
list of other js files that I am using on the website in the same order I have mentioned below.

```
1.3.2/jquery.min.js
1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js
ui.stars.min.js
jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js
jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.pack.js
```

I tried changing the version of  `jquery.min.js` to 1.9.1. but still i am getting the error.
and I am also using

```
<script src="cufon/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //statement
</script>
```

and

here is my custom javascript which is also included on to the website

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  /* Executed on DOM load */
  $("#slogan-addbutton").fancybox({
    'zoomSpeedIn': 600,
    'zoomSpeedOut': 500,
    'easingIn': 'easeOutBack',
    'easingOut': 'easeInBack',
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
    'padding': 15
  });
/* Listening for keyup events on fields of the "Add a note" form: */
    $('.pr-body,.pr-author').live('keyup',function(e){
        if(!this.preview)
            this.preview=$('#fancy_ajax .note');

        /* Setting the text of the preview to the contents of the input field, and stripping all the HTML tags: */
        this.preview.find($(this).attr('class').replace('pr-','.')).html($(this).val().replace(/<[^>]+>/ig,''));
    });

    /* Changing the color of the preview note: */
    $('.color').live('click',function(){
        $('#fancy_ajax .note').removeClass('yellow green blue').addClass($(this).attr('class').replace('color',''));
    });

    /* The submit button: */
    $('#note-submit').live('click',function(e){

        if($('.pr-body').val().length<4)
        {
            alert("The note text is too short!")
            return false;
        }

        if($('.pr-author').val().length<1)
        {
            alert("You haven't entered your name!")
            return false;
        }

        $(this).replaceWith('<img src="img/ajax_load.gif" style="margin:30px auto;display:block" />');

        var data = {
            'zindex'    : ++zIndex,
            'body'      : $('.pr-body').val(),
            'author'        : $('.pr-author').val(),
            'color'     : $.trim($('#fancy_ajax .note').attr('class').replace('note',''))
        };


        /* Sending an AJAX POST request: */
        $.post('post.php',data,function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg))
            {
                /* msg contains the ID of the note, assigned by MySQL's auto increment: */

                var tmp = $('#fancy_ajax .note').clone();

                tmp.find('span.data').text(msg).end().css({'z-index':zIndex,top:0,left:0});
                tmp.appendTo($('#main'));

                make_draggable(tmp)
            }

            $("#addButton").fancybox.close();
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    })

    $('.note-form').live('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();});


  $(".star-rating").stars();
  /* Converts all the radio groups into star ratings */

  $("#quotes-hide").mousemove(function (e) {
    /* The scrollable quote container */

    if (!this.hideDiv) {
      /* These variables are initialised only the firts time the function is run: */

      this.hideDiv = $(this);
      this.scrollDiv = $('#quotes-slide');

      this.pos = this.hideDiv.offset();
      this.pos.top += 20;
      /* Adding a 20px offset, so that the scrolling begins 20px from the top */


      this.slideHeight = this.scrollDiv.height();

      this.height = this.hideDiv.height();
      this.height -= 20;
      /* Adding a bottom offset */

      this.totScroll = this.slideHeight - this.height;
    }

    this.scrollDiv.css({
      /* Remember that this.scrollDiv is a jQuery object, as initilised above */

      marginTop: '-' + this.totScroll * (Math.max(e.pageY - this.pos.top, 0) / this.height) + 'px'
      /* Assigning a negative top margin according to the position of the mouse cursor, passed
               with e.pageY; It is relative to the page, so we substract the position of the scroll container */
    });

  });


  $('.thumb').click(function (e) {
    /* Executed once a quote from the list on the right is clicked */

    var obj = quotes[parseInt(e.target.id.replace('q-', '')) - 1];
    /* The e.target.id of the quote corresponds to its position in the quotes array */

    $('#slogan-quote-content').fadeOut('fast', function () {
      /* This is a callback function, run once the quote contaier on the left has faded out */

      if (!obj) return false;

      /* Replacing the contents of the quote text and author */

      $(this).find('h1').html(obj.txt);
      $(this).find('span').html(obj.author);

      /* Changing the background color */

      if (obj.bgc) $('body').stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: obj.bgc
      }, 'slow');

      /* Generating the radio boxes for the tool-tip star rating */

      var tmpstr = '';
      for (var z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
        tmpstr += '<input type="radio" name="voteQ" value="' + (z + 1) + '" ';

        if (z + 1 == obj.rating) tmpstr += 'checked=checked ';
        if (parseInt(obj.voted)) tmpstr += 'disabled="disabled" ';

        tmpstr += '/>';
      }

      tmpstr = '<div id="voteRating">' + tmpstr + '</div>';

      /* Updating the content of the tool-tip and converting it to a star rating */
      $('#slogan-box').qtip("api").updateContent(tmpstr);

      $('#voteRating').stars({
        cancelShow: false,
        oneVoteOnly: true,
        callback: function (ui, type, value) {
          vote(obj, value);
        }
      });

      /* Regenerating the cufon text replacement for the new quote text on the left */
      Cufon.refresh();

      /* Show the new quote with a fade-in effect */
      $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    });
  });

  /* Creating and configuring the tool-tip with the help of the qtip plugin */
  $('#slogan-box').qtip({
    content: {
      text: 'This is an active list element',
      title: {
        text: 'Vote for this quote'
      },
      prerender: true
    },

    show: 'mouseover',
    hide: {
      delay: 2000,
      fixed: true,
      when: 'mouseout'
    },
    position: {
      corner: {
        target: 'rightMiddle',
        tooltip: 'leftMiddle'
      },
      adjust: {
        y: 20
      }
    },
    style: {
      border: {
        width: 2,
        radius: 6
      },
      name: 'light',
      tip: 'leftMiddle'
    }
  });

  /* After the page has loaded, click the first quote on the right */
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#q-1').click();
  }, 250);
});

/* The global array holding all the data about the quotes. Filled in on page load. */
var quotes = new Array();

function fillData(obj) {
  quotes.push(obj);
}

function vote(ob, value) {
  /* Sending the votes to vote.php */
  $.post('vote.php', {
    qid: ob.id,
    vote: value
  }, function (data) {

    if (data == "1") {
      /* If the vote was saved successfully, update the quote data.. */
      ob.voted = 1;
      ob.votes = ob.votes + 1;
      ob.vsum = ob.vsum + parseInt(value);
      ob.rating = Math.round(ob.vsum / ob.votes);

      /* ..and update the star rating */
      $('#rating-' + ob.id).stars("select", ob.rating);
      quotes[ob.id - 1] = ob;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: jQuery v1.3.2 is **over 5 years old**, why are you still using it?

Comment: use a non minified version of the jQuery files... and then check the source of the error

Comment: I tried changing it to the new version.. but that doesnt help get rid of this problem. instead I do not see anything on my screen only.

Comment: I changed it to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js
 but I am getting - 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined jquery-ui.min.js:9`

Comment: How is this a php question?

Answer (score 6):

This may be due the other jQuery file included.

```
1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js
ui.stars.min.js
jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js
jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.pack.js
```

These files may have not been updated to be compatible with jquery.min.js(1.9.1). Some of these files may be using a function which has been deprecated in the 1.9.1 version of the jquery.

So try to find the compatible versions of these files and replace with new versions.
And change the deprecated methods with the new methods available in the 1.9.1.

For example:

```
.live(events, function) //was available in older versions and deprecated in 1.9.1 jquery
```

this has been mapped to:

```
.on(eventType, selector, function)  //in 1.9.1 jquery
```

Comment: I know this post is incredibly old, but so is WP's core jQuery (`1.12.4` on this day). The thing is, `.live` still works with that version - not sure why. However when someone enqueues a more modern jQuery (3.x) then it fails and throws the error you discussed above. Do you have any idea how we could support both?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to add this to the header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

This will make some uncompatible things to work with the new jQuery version.

It's not the best solution, but if you are in hurry it could help a lot.